# Filling an array before sending with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm not an expert at JavaScript (especially with promises and callbacks), but what I'm basically trying to do is make my JavaScript file synchronously do the following tasks: 
1. Create an array
2. Push every element I need into the array
3. Send the array to a controller with a post ajax call.
Here are the functions I am using:

```
function initialize() {
    var detroit = new google.maps.LatLng(42.331427, -83.0457538);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: detroit,
        zoom: 15
    });
    var request = {
        location: detroit,
        radius: 500,
        types: ['restaurant']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        service.search(request, callback);
    });
    promise.then(returnList);
}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            restaurantCount = results.length;
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });
        var request = {
            reference: place.reference
        };
        service.getDetails(request, function (details, status) {
            foodPlace = {
                PlaceID: details.place_id,
                Name: details.name,
                PriceLevel: details.price_level,
                WebSite: details.website,
                Rating: details.rating,
                AddressNumber: details.formatted_address,
                PhoneNumber: details.formatted_phone_number,
            };
            listOfRestaurants.push(foodPlace);
            //ajaxHelper('/api/Restaurants/', 'POST', foodPlace);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address + "<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number + "<br />" + details.price_level);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    }

    function returnList() {
        if (restaurantCount == listOfRestaurants.length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Index',
                data: listOfRestaurants,
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                success: alert("yay")
            }).fail(alert("oops"));
        }
    }
```

And the controller I'm making the POST call to is

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(List<Restaurant> restaurants)
{
    List<Restaurant> validRestaurants = new List<Restaurant>();

    foreach(Restaurant r in restaurants)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            validRestaurants.Add(r);
        }

    }

    return View(validRestaurants);
}
}
```

And in my code I have

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

to begin the initialize function when the window finishes loading.

The problem I'm having is that the data is always getting sent with the ajax call before the list has any data.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like you are `post`ing to your controller action before populating your `listOfRestaurants` object - is this a simple order of operations issue?

Comment: Hmm, where does your promise get resolved? Does the google service do this for you?

Comment: Can you please fix the curly braces. Right now the code is somewhat "strange"...

Comment: Yes wahwahwah, the order of operations is the issue. Seems like no matter what I try, the post happens before the array is populated. Thank you again for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `async: false` to your `returnList` callback, as it *allows* other request/operations to happen *only if* this request is over.

```
function returnList() {
    if (restaurantCount == listOfRestaurants.length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            async: false,
            data: listOfRestaurants,
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            success: alert("yay")
        }).fail(alert("oops"));
    }
}
```

***Note:*** As far as I think, you should be using `done()` instead of `then()` on the `promise` object, *since you want the `returnList` function to fetch/send the data only when the Defered is* *resolved*, and not to be called if the Deferred object is **either** *resolved, rejected, or still in progress* ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)).

Answer (score 0):

You are making an initial asynchronous call to get the places for a location, and when that returns, you are making multiple asynchronous calls to get the details for each place. You need to wait until all those calls return before you can post the data.

You can do this by creating an array of JQuery Deferred objects, one for each call to get the details for a place. You can then use the `$.when()` function to execute code after all those Deferred objects are resolved.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var detroit = new google.maps.LatLng(42.331427, -83.0457538);

    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: detroit,
        zoom: 15
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    var request = {
        location: detroit,
        radius: 500,
        types: ['restaurant']
    };

    // Make the request to get the places for the location.
    service.search(request, function(places, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            // For each place returned for the location, make a request to get
            // the details. An array of JQuery Deferred objects is created for
            // the requests.
            var deferreds = $.map(places, function(place) {
                return getDeferredFoodPlace(place);
            });

            // The "done" callback will be executed when all the Deferred
            // objects are resolved, that is, when all the requests for
            // details have returned.
            $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
                // Use "$.makeArray()" to convert the arguments to the
                // "done" callback to an array, and then use "$.map()"
                // to weed out the nulls.
                var foodPlaces = $.map($.makeArray(arguments), function(foodPlace) {
                    return foodPlace;
                });

                // Create the markers for the food places that were
                // successfully returned.
                $.each(foodPlaces, function(i, foodPlace) {
                     createMarker(foodPlace);
                });

                // This is where the food places that were successfully
                // returned can be posted to the server.
            });
        }
    });

    // This function creates a JQuery Deferred object that is resolved
    // when the service.getDetails() call returns. that is, when its
    // callback function is called.
    function getDeferredFoodPlace(place) {
        return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
            service.getDetails({
                reference: place.reference
            }, function(details, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    deferred.resolve({
                        Location: place.geometry.location,
                        PlaceID: details.place_id,
                        Name: details.name,
                        PriceLevel: details.price_level,
                        WebSite: details.website,
                        Rating: details.rating,
                        AddressNumber: details.formatted_address,
                        PhoneNumber: details.formatted_phone_number
                    });
                } else {
                    // If the call to get the details fails, this code
                    // will still resolve the Deferred object, but with
                    // a null value. Notice that null values are ignored
                    // in the "done" callback for the "$.when()" call.
                    // This means the places for which the details could
                    // not be obtained will simply be ignored with no
                    // error message.
                    // Alternatively, we could call ".reject()" instead
                    // of ".resolve()". That would cause the "fail"
                    // callback for the "$.when()" call to be executed.
                    // An error message could then be displayed, but
                    // it would mean everything fails if one fails.
                    deferred.resolve(null);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // This functions creates a marker on the map for the given food place.
    function createMarker(foodPlace) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: foodPlace.Location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(foodPlace.Name + "<br />"
                + foodPlace.AddressNumber + "<br />"
                + foodPlace.WebSite + "<br />"
                + foodPlace.Rating + "<br />"
                + foodPlace.PhoneNumber + "<br />"
                + foodPlace.PriceLevel);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hurwxx7L/2/)